# Infer generic type without widening

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following snippet the type of `y` is inferred as `Bar<{}>`, due to bivariance:

```
type Foo<A> = { type: "foo", x: A }
type Bar<A> = { type: "bar", y: A }

type FooBar<A> = Foo<A> | Bar<A>

type Opposite<A, FB extends FooBar<A>> = FB["type"] extends "foo" ? Bar<A> : Foo<A>

declare function process<A, FB extends FooBar<A>>(foo: FB): Opposite<A, FB>

const x: Foo<number> = null as any

const y = process(x) // Bar<{}>
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20Foo%3CA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20x%3A%20A%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Bar%3CA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%20y%3A%20A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FooBar%3CA%3E%20%3D%20Foo%3CA%3E%20%7C%20Bar%3CA%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Opposite%3CA%2C%20FB%20extends%20FooBar%3CA%3E%3E%20%3D%20FB%5B%22type%22%5D%20extends%20%22foo%22%20%3F%20Bar%3CA%3E%20%3A%20Foo%3CA%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20process%3CA%2C%20FB%20extends%20FooBar%3CA%3E%3E(foo%3A%20FB)%3A%20Opposite%3CA%2C%20FB%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20Foo%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20null%20as%20any%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20y%20%3D%20process(x)%20%2F%2F%20Bar%3C%7B%7D%3E)

Can I preserve the generic type `A` so that `process(x)` returns `Bar<number>` without specifying it explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inferring `A` based on the type constraint of `FB` is not something typescript will really do. Since the parameters offer no site to infer `A`, typescript will infer the widest possible type for `A` which is `{}`

You can use a conditional type to extract `A` from the type parameter `FB`:

```
type Foo<A> = { type: "foo", x: A }
type Bar<A> = { type: "bar", y: A }

type FooBar<A> = Foo<A> | Bar<A>

type Opposite<A, FB extends FooBar<A>> = FB["type"] extends "foo" ? Bar<A> : Foo<A>

type FooBarParam<T> = T extends FooBar<infer A> ? A : never;
declare function process<FB extends FooBar<any>>(foo: FB): Opposite<FooBarParam<FB>, FB>

const x: Foo<number> = null as any

const y = process(x) // Bar<number>
```

Comment: I just wanted to tell you I'm really impressed with your typescript answers :-)

Comment: @zerkms 10x :) It's nice to be appreciated :D